# inserting values into specific rows with SQL

Tags: sql

I Have a table of bike details and I want to add different prices to different bike types using SQL queries, but what I have gives me a syntax error:

```
INSERT INTO bike (full_day)
VALUES (10)
WHERE bike_type = 'mens_hybrid';
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

An [`INSERT` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-insert.html) is only for creating completely new records, not for populating data into existing ones. What you need is an [`UPDATE` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-update.html), which updates an existing record:

```
UPDATE bike SET full_day = 10 WHERE bike_type = 'mens_hybrid';
```

---

(Note: below is an earlier version of this answer, from before it was clear to me what the original poster was trying to do. I'm leaving it here because multiple people who originally answered this question did not seem to notice the problem with writing `INSERT ... VALUES (...) WHERE`, which makes me think that this explanation might be useful to some people coming across this question.)

---

That statement doesn't make sense. An `INSERT` can't take a `WHERE` clause, because `WHERE` refers to existing records, and an `INSERT` creates new ones.

(To forestall potential confusion: there exists such a thing as `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`, where the records to insert are determined by a `SELECT` query rather than by a `VALUES` expression, and in that case the `SELECT` query can, of course, have a `WHERE` clause. But in no case does the `WHERE` clause belong to the `INSERT` statement directly.)

Comment: How would I add the value 10 to that column only where the bike model is mens mountain bike

Comment: @Matt: I don't know if you saw, but I edited my answer; everything from the word **Update** onward is new, and I *think* it's what you're looking for. If it isn't, then you might have to post some sample data, showing how your table will look before and after you run the statement.

Comment: @Matt: Also, what DBMS are you using? (MySQL? PostgreSQL? Oracle? SQL Server?) I can add links to the relevant documentation, which you'll probably find helpful, but the detailed rules depend a bit on the DBMS, so I don't want to post (say) Oracle docs if you're using (say) MySQL.

Comment: we must have edited at the same time, this is great thanks, btw I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: @Matt: You're welcome! I've edited the answer to link to the relevant PostgreSQL documentation pages: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-insert.html for INSERT, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-update.html for UPDATE.